# The A20 Line with JOS

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, gdt

The snippet code as following is enable A20 for JOS. It has a problem which confuse for me. The "$0xdf" is a command, not data.
It should be out to port 0x64, which is command port. In fact, It port to 0x60, which is data port.
Here, exist two methods (Method 3.1 & Method 3.2) : 
http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev9.html

So, my question is : Why port to 0x60 (outb %al, %0x60) at last ?

```
seta20.1:
  inb     $0x64,%al               # Wait for not busy
  testb   $0x2,%al
  jnz     seta20.1

  movb    $0xd1,%al               # 0xd1 -> port 0x64
  outb    %al,$0x64                                                                                

seta20.2:
  inb     $0x64,%al               # Wait for not busy
  testb   $0x2,%al
  jnz     seta20.2

  movb    $0xdf,%al               # 0xdf -> port 0x60
  outb    %al,$0x60
```

Comment: Yes, it's work.

https://github.com/ych/6.828/blob/lab1/boot/boot.S

Comment: Turns out `0xdf` is used to enable A20 (use 0xdd to disable).

Comment: The keyboard controller has three 8-bit registers involved in communication with the CPU: its input buffer, that can be written by the CPU by writing port 0x60 or port 0x64; its output buffer, that can be read by the CPU by reading from port 0x60; and the status register, that can be read by the CPU by reading from port 0x64.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a standard procedure. As said in my comment, port 0x60 is keyboard-related. But it is not its sole function.

### Classical A20 control, via the keyboard controller

> The output port of the keyboard controller has a number of functions. 
>   Bit 0 is used to reset the CPU (go to real mode) - a reset happens
>   when bit 0 is 0.  Bit 1 is used to control A20 - it is enabled when
>   bit 1 is 1, disabled when bit 1 is 0.  One sets the output port of the
>   keyboard controller by first writing 0xd1 to port 0x64, and the the
>   desired value of the output port to port 0x60. One usually sees the
>   values 0xdd and 0xdf used to disable/enable A20. Thus:

```
call    empty_8042
mov     al,#0xd1                ! command write
out     #0x64,al
call    empty_8042
mov     al,#0xdf                ! A20 on
out     #0x60,al
call    empty_8042
```

*Source:* [*A20 - a pain from the past*](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/A20.html)

Comment: Thanks.Here, it's picture for KBC. http://aodfaq.wikispaces.com/mkbc

The port 0x60 is Data Port, 0xD1 and 0xDF is a command, not Data.

So, my question become that "Why send the Command (0xD1, 0xDF, 0xDD) to the Data Port (0x60)? It should be Command Port (0x64)."

Comment: @Gapry `0xDD`, sent to port `0x60` is used to disable `A20`. `0xDF` is to enable it. As for `0xD1`, I do not know. Why port `0x60`? It is in the answer: `The output port of the keyboard controller has a number of functions. Bit 0 is used to reset the CPU (go to real mode)… [ ... ] One usually sees the values 0xdd and 0xdf used to disable/enable A20.` So, it should not be the port `0x64`, but the port `0x60` (keyboard) indeed. In your picture, in front of port `0x60` one reads  `out -> A20 gate`. The instruction matches this scheme: `out #0x60,al`

Comment: Thanks. :-) 

It seems to help me to understand deeply

Answer (score 1):

To send a command to the PS/2 controller, simply write the command byte to IO port 0x64. If there is a "next byte" then the next byte needs to be written to IO Port 0x60 after making sure that the controller is ready for it (by making sure bit 1 of the Status Register is clear).

Thus after sending 0xd1 to Port 0x64, the command 0xdf is sent to Port 0x60, which enables A20.

If there is a response byte, then the response byte needs to be read from IO Port 0x60 after making sure that it has arrived (by making sure bit 0 of the Status Register is set).

Source: [PS/2_Controller - osdev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller)